# How to input a three dimensional array in C-PLEX software?

Tags: 3d, range, operator-keyword, cplex, circular-dependency

I want to input the state of charge of 100 vehicles connected each bus of a 14 bus system for each hour on a 24h basis. First I want to start with first bus. Then I want to check for state of charge of 100 vehicles connected to first bus. Then want to check state of charge of 100 vehicles connected to second bus for a 24 h period. For tis how can I set up a data file.

```
int nb=14;
int  t=24;
int nv=100;
range  nbus=1..nb;
range tavail =1..t;
range  nport=1..nv;
float soc[nbus*tavail*nport]=...;
float array[i in nbus,j in tavail,k in nport]=soc[k+nport*(j-1)+tavail*nport*(i-1)];
execute {
   writeln(array);
};
```

I entered a  code like this .But it is showing circular dependency of soc and operator not available for range*range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine:

```
int nb=14;
int  t=24;
int nv=100;
range  nbus=1..nb;
range tavail =1..t;
range  nport=1..nv;
float soc[i in 1..nb*t*nv]=i;


float array[i in nbus,j in tavail,k in nport]=soc[(i-1)*t*nv+(j-1)*nv+(k-1)+1];
execute {
   writeln(array);
};

{float} values={array[i][j][k]| i in nbus,j in tavail,k in nport};

assert check:card(values)==nb*t*nv;
```

Comment: Sir, it is not showing an error during the initialization part. However, writing the constraint as soc[k][j][i] indicates that it is not an array type. Also, I want to know how I can arrange the data type for the three-dimensional array from an Excel file. Soc[14] [24] [100] is the dimension of my array.

Comment: For reading from Excel see https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/read3Darray.mod

Comment: I think here I must input these data as tuple sets, as shown in the examples you have provided for read3Darray.dat and read3Darray.mod. Can you provide some details about how the execution of a tuple set is being done? That is to say, here is my problem: soc [i] [j]. [k] denotes that i ranges from 1...14, j ranges from 1...24, and k ranges from 1...100. I'd like to start with i = 1 and j = 1, then k = 1...100, then update the value of j, and finally k = 1...100. When the limit of j is reached, I want to go back to i = 2 and repeat the process.